# Rationale for why JavaScript converts primitive values to numbers in == operator comparisons when one is boolean?

Tags: javascript

I know the rule:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible.

So, `if("true")` passes but `if("true" == true)` fails because it is handle like  `if(NaN == 1)`.

I was wondering what the rational is behind this when one value is boolean.  In other weak typed languages like php, this is handle this differently--if one value is a boolean, the other is converted to a boolean for comparisons (and not covert both to numbers as in javascript).

I'm assuming this choice was made for the `==` operator on careful consideration.  Can anyone provide rational as to why this was the chosen functionality?  Is there a common use case that this was chosen to address?  I'm betting is wasn't just a mistake.

Comment: Direct comparisons to boolean values are *usually* a questionable practice.

Comment: While agreeing with @Pointy, it's even weirder. The only number that is true is 1. `( 2 == true ) == false`. Although not providing an answer, the solution is not to compare "things" (objects or arbitrary sizes) with a boolean value

Comment: FYI, you can convert any value to boolean for this by using two *not* operators, e.g., `if(!!"true" == true)`.  (Generally doing `if("true")` is easier, but just in case you need to compare a value to true, for some reason.)

Comment: So, are you asking why the people working on the ECMAScript standard decided to do so? You might have more luck asking them directly.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand says something important. If you want to check if a string is true, just use it in a boolean expression (but **not** comparing it with true). Any string which is non-empty is true

Comment: @gustafr yes it is odd, but what I meant was that if you've got a value that you expect to be boolean, there's no reason to explicitly compare it to `true` or `false`.  Thus if there's a comparison being made between two expressions, the type conversion logic tries to do the comparisons in a way that's likely to be "useful". (At least that's what I've always thought.)

Comment: *"Most other languages I'm well versed in (java, php...) handle this differently"* Huh? Java is strong typed, not weak typed.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - careful, !!("true") and !!("false") both return true

Comment: @BalusC sorry, mistyped.  you're correct java doesn't act in this way.  editing my question.

Comment: @FelixKling I probably will submit a question to them if I can't get the answer quickly on SO.  Because you can possibly find something elsewhere is no reason not to try SO with an army of folks looking to provide an answer.  Most questions on SO could be  responded with 'RTFM' or 'write their specific user community/developer forum', but truth be told, it's usually faster and more educational to work with the SO community.

Comment: I agree and you could even answer the question yourself once you get the answer from one of the officials. Asking for the reasoning behind certain decisions is just something very specific and it's more likely you get the *true* reasons from official sources. Just wanted to help even if it sounded a bit grumpy :)

Comment: @FelixKling Just sent out the email to their mailing list.  Stay tuned...

Comment: @FelixKling see my answer--from the horse's mouth so to speak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A remarkably quick response just in from Brendan Eich from the es-discuss@mozilla.org mailing list :

Consider Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'print 0 == "true";'
1
```

Ok, poor rationale -- but I created JS in May 1995, in the shadow of AWK, Perl 4, Python 1.2 (IIRC), TCL.

I should have paid more attention to AWK than Perl, given

```
$ awk 'END {print(0 == "0")}'
1D
$ awk 'END {print(0 == "")}'
0D
```

In some ways, JS's `==` operator splits the difference between Perl (where non-numeric strings such as `"true"` convert to `0`) and AWK (where only `"0"` converts to `0`) by converting to NaN. That way, at least, we have

```
js> 0 == ""
true
js> 0 == "true"
false
```

But the full truth is not that I was carefully emulating other languages. Rather, some Netscapers working to embed JS (then "Mocha") in a PHP-like server (LiveWire) wanted sloppy conversions, so programmers could match HTTP header strings (server side) or HTML form fields (client side) against, e.g., 404 and the like, without explicit coercion by the programmer.

But it was the 90s, I was in a tearing hurry, these ex-Borland Netscapers were persistent. So, as I said at [Strange Loop last year](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/State-JavaScript), "I was an idiot! I gave them what they wanted!"

Implicit conversions are my biggest regret in JS's rushed design, bar none. Even including 'with'!

> Does anyone know the exact reason the choice was made not to convert to boolean any value compared against a boolean in with the == operator?

The general idea is the narrower type should widen. Thus, `true == 1` follows by projecting boolean `{false, true}` onto `{0, 1}`, as in C++.

But why not widen `true` to string, since the other operand in your example is `"true"`? Good question. The bias toward comparing strings as numbers if either operand is a number or a boolean stems from the HTTP header and numeric-string HTML form field use-cases. Not good reasons, again, but that's how JS "works" :-|.

You can see this in the ECMA-262 Edition 5.1 spec, 11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm, steps 6 & 7 (read in light of steps 4 & 5):

4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

This is all in a big "else clause where `Type(x)` and `Type(y)` for `x == y` are not the same.

Sorry there's no pearl (sic) of wisdom here. In addition to implicit conversions, `==` and `!=` do not widen operands directly (no intermediate conversions) to the narrowest width that can hold the other operand without data loss. This narrowing string to number is just a botch.

If we fixed this botch, we'd still have:

```
0 == "0"
1 == "1"
true != "1"
false != "0"
```

But we would also have what your example wants:

```
true == "true"
false != ""
```

Per my calling the preference for number over string conversion a botch, we would not have `true == "1"` or `false == "0"`, because that narrows from string to number. It's true the narrowing loses no bits, and one can widen `0` back to `"0"` and `1` back to `"1"`, but I meant to illustrate what removing all number-over-string bias from the implicit conversion spec for == would do.

Would such a change break a lot of code on the web? I'd bet large sums it would.

Some take this botch, on top of any implicit conversion under the hood, as another reason to use `===` and `!==` always (because they never convert), and to utterly shun `==` and `!=`. Others disagree (especially when testing `x == null`, a one-operator way to `test x === null || x === undefined`).

Since the web grows mostly-compatibly until very old forms die off, we're stuck with `==` and `!=`, so I say it pays to learn what the sloppy equality operators do. Having done that, it seems to me one may use them where they win: when you know the operands are same-type, e.g.

`typeof x == "function"`, etc.
`x == null`

And otherwise, use `===` and `!==`.

The bias toward comparing strings as numbers if either operand is a number or a boolean stems from the HTTP header and numeric-string HTML form field use-cases. Not good reasons, again, but that's how JS "works" :-|.

One more note: it could be argued that narrowing from string to number would be ok (as in, useful most of the time, and not unsafe) if any non-numeric, non-empty string-to-number implicit conversion attempt threw an exception.

Here's where another path-dependent bias in JS's design bit: no try/catch in JS1 or any ECMA-262 standard till ES3.

The lack of exception handling also meant `undefined` is imputed for missing `obj.foo` property get where `obj` has no such property. That is still biting back, perhaps as much as or more than implicit conversions bite `==`. It is also the basis of web JS's winning "object detection" pattern, which fairly beats all other versioning schemes I've seen, especially a-priori ones based on explicit numbering and opt-in.

If only I'd taken the time to add an existential operator for object detection, so one could write

```
function emulateRequestAnimationFrame(...) {...}
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame?)
  window.requestAnimationFrame = emulateRequestAnimationFrame;
```

IOW, if only I'd made `window.noSuchProperty` throw but `window.noSuchProperty?` evaluate to truthy or `false` (details still TBD, see the "fail-fast object destructuring" thread revival, the Nil idea).

Comment: Cool. I wanted to format the post to convert the code formatting to quotes, but I wasn't sure whether the second one is from you or Brendan... could please format the post as good as possible to make it clear what he wrote, what was your question (what he might have quoted), etc?

Comment: That's a great response. I guess I helped by providing the link to the mailing list. :P

Answer (score 3):

I think some clarification is in order. According to the ECMA specification the *entire* expression for the if statement (the part within the parentheses) is converted to a boolean.

So imagine it like this:

```
if (ToBoolean("true" == true)) {  //false
```

vs

```
if (ToBoolean("true")) { //true
```

I suppose the rational for why the ToBoolean coercion was added to the if expression was to ensure the expression always evaluates safely and correctly.

ToBoolean coerces a single value to a boolean. A comparison does not coerce each value to a boolean, that wouldn't make sense as you get some pretty strange results. It checks for equality, a different operation. As for why one value isn't converted to boolean when the other is one I am not sure, but try the Mozilla ECMA mailing list: https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss

See:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1

Comment: Isn't the question more about the comparison operator than the `if` statement?

Comment: The comparison operator only calls GetValue for each of the values it compares. It does not call ToBoolean according to the spec. The conversion expressed in the question only happens inside an if statement or other contexts in which ToBoolean is called. I interpreted the question to be why is ToBoolean called for if statements expressions, as that makes more sense given the spec.

Comment: I think you missed step 5 for the [comparison operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.1): *"5. Return the result of performing abstract equality comparison rval == lval. (see [11.9.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3))."* And that's where all the magic happens. The conversion takes place whether or not the operator is used in an `if` statement.

Comment: ToBoolean coerces a single value to a boolean. A comparison does not coerce each value to a boolean, that wouldn't make sense. It checks for equality.

Comment: No, but the comparison produces one single value. And the question was about why, if two values are compared and one is a boolean, both of those values are converted to numbers.

Comment: True. I missed this when I initially answered because I focused on the some issues I had with the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: @BjornTipling Just sent an email to their mailing list.  Will report back.

Comment: I was going to do it if you weren't. :P

Comment: @BjornTipling See my answer, from Brendan Eich via the mailing list.